# How can I clear browser cache (memory / disk cache) after logout?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, browser-cache

I use asp net core mvc + js. One type of my pages have cache.

```
[ResponseCache(Location = ResponseCacheLocation.Client, Duration = 60)]
public async Task<IActionResult> StaticContent(string path)
{
    // code
}
```

I have a problem when user logout on this page. User sees his account after logout because page was cache. If refresh page cache clear and user does not see account.

I try ***location.reload();*** on js when logout click but reload work earlier than logout work on server. I try change Vary header but I change Vary only page which I redirect after logout

How can I clear cache after logout? Any ideas?

Comment: _"User sees his account"_ - And the problem with that is? Its his account even after logout.

Comment: @Andreas The user is logged out of their account, but sees it

Comment: Why not exclude this page from cache?

Comment: @Adlorem Because this is not one page but many of them

Comment: I found this strange *If refresh page cache clear and user does not see account* - if it's cached (and not depending on the state of logged-in or not), it will only be cleared ***by expiration***. So refreshing the page will not clear the cache unless it's done right after the expiration. So please retry your steps and confirm that fact. If it still remains, there must be something clearing the cache from the server side, such as in your middlewares ... it's hard to tell.

Comment: So let me get this straight: you're explicitly telling the browser to cache this page for an hour; and you're getting upset that the browser is doing what you told it to. Why not, I dunno, **not cache the page**?

Answer (score 1):

I find answer on microsoft site https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/response?view=aspnetcore-5.0#responsecache-attribute
They say don`t cache content which using user info.

I cache individual parts of page without account info.
I use

```
<cache expires-after="" />
```

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

As the King King says, if you enable the client cache , there is no way to tell the client side in the server-side. The only way is just tell the CX to clear the cache. Since once the browser obeys the cache rules you send here, the only opportunity you will have to retract your cache rules is the next time the browser requests the page.

Normally, the dynamic pages should not attempt to set client-side caching if you want them to stay dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

In your logout post, you can clear a session that may solve your problem.

```
HttpContext.Session.Clear(); //this will clear all session 
HttpContext.Session.Remove("sessionName"); //this will clear a specific session
```